# Having one simple model for generic information and other that plug more fields in it

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, database-performance

I have an app where people can add their stuff to the catalog. Now the thing is, that generic catalog/listing models only allow you to add basic product information, such as the these:

```
Title: My awesome laptop
Category: fk:123 (resolved: u'Electronics > Computers > Laptops')
Seller: fk: 1653 (resolved: u'DudeNobodyKnows')
PriceValue: 100 (resolved: u'100.00,-')
PriceCurrency: fk:15 (resolved: u'€ (EUR)')
DateAdded: 2013-09-02 (resolved: u'2nd September 2013')
Description: u'I just hate it and want to sell it.\
               I can give you a 10% off if you buy\
               this thing by 4rd September 2013.

               = Specs =
               CPU: Intel Core i7 2770k
               RAM: 64GiB DDR3 Dual-Channel ECC FB-DIMM 1666 MHz
               HDD: Kingston HyperX SSDNow V300 120 GiB

               Contact: +12 123456789
                        em@il.com'
```

etc.

I want this `= Specs =` section to lie ENTIRELY in the Laptop-specific model. I want this catalog to be fully specific. I want the viewer to be able to find some Computer running Intel® processor with at least 2 cores and at least 16 GiB's of RAM and either 10K HDD or an SSD and the screen size should be no bigger than 15" etc. I want him to be able to enter this information to a search form and I want him to be able to find this laptop, because it more-than-meets his requirements (even though the screen size is unknown, but that would just move it in the "Requirements not fully met" section in the listing).

What is the best approach to make this work?

Should I just have one model for the generic info and then "plug" individual components in that model? Like having an Offer with Who's selling it and for what price (and that information) and then add individual items as foreign keys? Having this in a Category model: id, title, parent(manytomany), description and AllowedModels aka stuff you can put into that category and it's children (like you can't put jewelry to Graphic Cards category). Then make a Model for every thing that could be possibly sold in that app, like Laptop, Car, Bolt, Guitar, Speaker, etc. and make another batch of subcategories which will extend them (like

```
Laptop: Thin Client
        Netbook
        ThoughBook
        Office Laptop
        General Purpose Laptop
        Multimedia Laptop
        Business Laptop
        Gaming Laptop
        Professional Laptop
        MacBook
```

etc.

Is that a correct approach? The same with Brands (Apple makes Laptops, Desktops, Tablets, Phones, but not Drills, Hammers, Cars or Mugs)

In a PC area, make a LOT of presets (all CPUs and GPUs sold in last 10 years etc.) and calling those components as Many-To-Many keys - you can have a computer with 2 Xeon CPUs and 16 RAM DIMMs and badass 16-disk SSD RAID array, right?

Is this extending and plugging all the tings together corrrect approach? Or is it just better to leave it as it is in the first example?

Is this very, very specific approact an 'OK' way? Will it introduce a heavy performance impact? Oh and I'm doing everything in PostgreSQL…

Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into model inheritance?

If not, its probably time you give it a read. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

They way it works at the implementation level is, you define a "base" class which contains all the base details.

A very simplified example might be something like this

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    price = models.CharField()
    location = models.CharField()
    catgegory = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Computer(Item):
    CPU = models.CharField()
    RAM = models.CharField()
    HDD = models.CharField()
```

The `abstract = True` line indicates that Django shouldn't make a database table for it. Its a generic base class for other classes to extend.

Because the Computer class inherits from the Item class, it has access to all its attributes .  You can even extend the computer class into two Desktop and Laptop classes.

If you don't already know about inheritance, I strongly suggest reading more about it. Wikipedia is always a good place to start :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: Well, that escalated quickly…
I wrote an essay and the (possible) answer is SO simple…

Comment: Actually if you don't already know about inheritance, I suggest you read into it. It is an important feature of object orientated languages. I'll update my answer to include a link.